# Is there an available feature model and code of a dynamic software product line (DSPL)?

Tags: reference-request, software-engineering

Dynamic Software Product Lines (DSPLS) are software product lines (SPLs) where features can be bound and unbound during program execution time.

Is there a feature model and code available of an DSPL? I.e., where the model and the implementation is freely available for research purposes? I mean for regular SPLs there is the [SPLOT website](http://www.splot-research.org/) for models and there are several [Fuji exmaples](http://www.infosun.fim.uni-passau.de/spl/apel/Fuji/#download) where the implementaiton code is downloadable.

I contacted one of the authors of a review paper on DSPLs:
Hallsteinsen, S., Hinchey, M., Park, S., & Schmid, K. (2008). Dynamic software product lines. Computer, 41(4), 93-95.

He answered me that he is not aware of any available DSPL! He said that some work is government funded or sponsored by companies and in both cases it is impossible to get anything, let alone code. However, the feature model and code excerpts that I am interested in can be easily anonymised.

Is it true that there is not a single DSPL where the model and some implementation code is availiable?

Are there any research groups I could contact in this regard? Groups that might have a DSPL feature model or implementation that might be available for research? The feature model and implementation code can be anonymized.

The reason for my question is that I am interested in analyzing DSPLs, but it seems impossible to get a DSPL anywhere; although, incidentally, there a numerous papers on DSPLs.

Comment: ok, I just realized you mentioned "during program execution time", which completely invalidates my answer. I'll delete it to avoid misunderstandings.

Comment: @rla4 anyways, what was your answer about? perhaps you can make a short comment?

Comment: Sure, I mentioned MobileMedia [(source code)](http://www.ic.unicamp.br/~tizzei/mobilemedia/): a Software Product Line (SPL) that manipulates photo, music, and video on mobile devices. They built an AspectJ version of it (look for the AO tagged folders in the CVS repository), and turning features on or off is basically a matter of turning the aspects on or off (that is, compiling the source code with or without AspectJ support). This ICSE paper explains the project a bit better: FIGUEIREDO, E., et al. Evolving Software Product Lines with Aspects: An Empirical Study on Design Stability.